# Issue with recreating XMLHttpRequest via Python Requests and Postman

Tags: python, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest, python-requests, postman

I'm trying to shorten links on bit.do using Python or Postman.
[image: bit.do url shortener form]
In Chrome everything works fine. But not with Python/Postman. I get the page, but there is only error, however request from Chrome and request that I'm trying to make looks the same.
Using Chrome Dev Tools captured two POST requests, both named `url-shortener.pl`.
Here are these requests (SO forced me not to use links from URL shorteners, so I had to escape them.):

```
General:
Request URL: https://bit\.do/mod_perl/url-shortener.pl
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 
Remote Address: 54.83.52.76:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response Headers:
content-type: application/json
date: Sat, 20 Apr 2019 20:12:06 GMT
server: nginx/1.14.1
status: 200

Request Headers:
:authority: bit\.do
:method: POST
:path: /mod_perl/url-shortener.pl
:scheme: https
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,ru-RU;q=0.8,ru;q=0.7
content-length: 112
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
cookie: permasession=1554914974|phkaoymp1b; __utmc=60667454; __utma=60667454.372171702.1554914974.1555785612.1555789898.5; __utmz=60667454.1555789898.5.4.utmcsr=dynomapper.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/blog/21-sitemaps-and-seo/495-top-14-url-shorteners; __utmt=1; __utmb=60667454.3.10.1555789898
origin: https://bit\.do
referer: https://bit\.do/
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36
x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest

Form Data:
action: shorten
url: google.com
url2:  site2 
url_hash: 
url_stats_is_private: 0
permasession: 1554914974|phkaoymp1b


General:
Request URL: https://bit\.do/mod_perl/url-shortener.pl
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200

Response Headers: 
Remote Address: 54.83.52.76:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
content-type: application/json
date: Sat, 20 Apr 2019 20:12:06 GMT
server: nginx/1.14.1
status: 200

Request Headers:
:authority: bit\.do
:method: POST
:path: /mod_perl/url-shortener.pl
:scheme: https
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,ru-RU;q=0.8,ru;q=0.7
content-length: 32
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
cookie: permasession=1554914974|phkaoymp1b; __utmc=60667454; __utma=60667454.372171702.1554914974.1555785612.1555789898.5; __utmz=60667454.1555789898.5.4.utmcsr=dynomapper.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/blog/21-sitemaps-and-seo/495-top-14-url-shorteners; __utmt=1; __utmb=60667454.3.10.1555789898
origin: https://bit\.do
referer: https://bit\.do/
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36
x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest

Form Data:
action: get_title
url_id: 49444432
```

Firstly I tried with Postman. Params:
[image: postman post request parameters]
Headers:
[image: postman post request headers]
Response preview:
[image: postman response preview]
As a result: ERROR: Invalid url. Please enter a valid url address.
Then I switched to Python and tried with Requests.

```python
def bitdo():
    headers = {
        'accept': '*/*',
        'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,ru-RU;q=0.8,ru;q=0.7',
        'content-length': '112',
        'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
        'cookie': 'permasession=1554914974|phkaoymp1b; __utmc=60667454; __utma=60667454.372171702.1554914974.1555785612.1555789898.5; __utmz=60667454.1555789898.5.4.utmcsr=dynomapper.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/blog/21-sitemaps-and-seo/495-top-14-url-shorteners; __utmt=1; __utmb=60667454.3.10.1555789898',
        'origin': 'https://bit\.do',
        'referer': 'https://bit\.do/',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36'
    }
    params = {
        'action': 'shorten',
        'url': 'ya.ru',
        'url2': 'site2',
        'url_hash': '',
        'url_stats_is_private': 0,
        'permasessions': '1554914974|phkaoymp1b'
    }

    r = requests.post('https://bit\.do/mod_perl/url-shortener.pl', params, headers=headers)
    print(r.text)
```

And the response was:

```html
<title>Warning</title>

<!-- head.thtml -->
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">


<style type="text/css">

a { color: #338; text-decoration: none; }

html {
 height: 100%;
}

body {
 font-family: Arial;
 margin: 0;
 height: 100%;
 color: #404040;
}

.url {
 background-color: #f9f9f9;
 width: 100%;
 height: 16px;
 border: 1px solid #654;
 padding: 3px;
}

.round {
 background-color: white;
 border: 1px solid #bbb;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 -moz-border-radius: 15px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
 border-radius: 15px;
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 840px;
}

.input-placeholder {
 position: absolute;
 font-style: italic;
 color: #aaa;
 margin: 0.3em 0 0 0.5em;
}

.orange_logo {
  color: #fab035;
}

.orange_text {
 color: #D04000;
}

.orange_dot {
 color: #ff8800;
 margin-left: 10px;
}


.table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #efefef;
}

.table1 {
 border-spacing: 0;
 border-collapse: collapse;
}

.table1 th {
 text-align: center;
}

.table1 td, .table1 th {
 border: 1px solid #a0a0a0;
 padding: 5px;
}

.bitbox {
 width: 100%;
}

/* first td should have minimal width */
.bitbox td:first-child {
 width: 12px;
 padding-right: 12px;
 white-space: nowrap;
}

</style>


<body>

<div style="
 height: 30px; 
 line-height: 30px;
 background-color: #fab035;
 xtext-align: right;
 color: black; 
 padding-right: 10px;
 font-size: 0.8em;
">

<a href="http://bit.do/"><img src="/images/bit-do-url-shortener-logo-66x66.png"
alt="URL Shortener - bit.do"
style="
 width: 31px;
 height: 31px;
 margin-left: 80px;
 margin-right: 10px;
vertical-align: middle;
"
></a>

<!--
Create short link: 
<input placeholder="http://...">
-->


<!--
<b>
<a href="http://bit.do/" style="color: black">bit.do - URL Shortener</a>
</b>
-->

<!--
<a href="/admin" style="color: black">Login to manage your links</a>
-->



<table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width=100%>

<tr>
 <td class=top_left>&nbsp;</td>
 <td class=top_middle><b>Warning</b></td>
 <td class=top_right>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td class=middle_left></td>
 <td class=middle_middle>



<ul>
<br>
<pre class="warning_message">ERROR site2: Can not create short link. Contact us for API usage.
</pre>

<p>
<br>
<br>





<br>
<br>
<br>





</ul>
<p>
<a href="http://bit.do/" class="button">&#8617; Back to bit.do (url shortener)</a>

<p>


</td>
</tr>
</table>
<!-- /table all -->


<p style="float: right; text-align: right; font-size: 0.8em; color: #808080; margin: 0; margin-right: 10px;">
Follow us on Twitter: <b><a href="https://twitter.com/bitdo" target=_blank class="orange_logo" style="border: 0;">@bitdo</a>&nbsp;</b>
</p>
<br style="clear: both;">
<hr style="
 border: 0px;
 height: 1px;
 background-color: #e0e0e0;
 xbackground-color: #fab035;

">

<div style="
 margin: 0 auto;
 text-align: center;
 xbackground-color: #c8c8c8;
 bottom: 0px;
"
>
<span style="font-size: 0.7em; line-height: 35px;">
Shorten and personalize long web addresses. Get real-time traffic statistics for your links. Free service.<br>
</span>
<span style="font-size: 15px; font-family: arial;">

<a href="http://bit.do/">bit.do - home</a>

<span style="color:#bbbbbb">|</span>
<a href="/best-url-shortener.php">why bit.do is better</a>
<span style="color:#bbbbbb">|</span>
<a href="/about-us.php">about us</a> 
<span style="color:#bbbbbb">|</span>
<a href="/what-is-url-shortener.php">about url shortener</a>
<span style="color:#bbbbbb">|</span>
<a href="/contact.php">contact</a>

<!--
<a href="">FAQ</a> |
<a href="">terms</a> |
-->
</span>
<p style="margin: 7px; color: #909090; font-size: 0.5em;">
Copyright &copy; 2019 - Insite</p>

</div> <!-- /foot -->


</div>
<!-- /height 100% -->

<!-- TODO: ALREADY LOADED ? -->
<script src="/js/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-756399-13']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>

</html>

<!-- END OF erro.thtml -->
```

ERROR site2: Can not create short link. Contact us for API usage.

I expect to get shortened links inside HTML response. Can someone explain me what was wrong with requests I did?

Comment: when I run page in browser I see POST with data in body, not in url. So you need `data=params`, not `params`

Comment: and remove  \  from all `bit\.do`

Comment: in browser in params I see `+site2+` not `site2`. You may have to also first make GET to get unique cookies `permasessions`

Comment: when you send POST then you don't have to set `'content-length': '112',` it should calculate this size based on data in params.

Comment: @furas, thank you for the response! Body? But request's content-type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded. I mentioned '\' in my post (SO doesn't allow shortened links). I tried both site2 and +site2+. Also tried without headers.

Comment: in body like every POST, not in url `?action=...` like GET.

Comment: @furas, of course, my fault. When tried to make GET no cookies were returned.

Comment: @furas, moved payload to the body. Also ommited content-length. Response from Postman: ERROR +site2+: Can not create short link. Contact us for API usage.

Comment: finally I made it with requests. It has to be space instead of `+` in `+site2+`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems minimal working code.

It needs header `'X-Requested-With'` because it is AXAJ/XHR request.

It needs `permasession` but first `GET` doesn't send it so probably it is generated on page with JavaScript. But it works for me with the same `permasession` all the time.

Maybe later it will need new/fresh `permasession`

There are spaces in `" site2 "`

```
import requests

headers={
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest', # need it
}

data = {
    'action': 'shorten',
    'url': 'https://onet.pl',
    'url2': ' site2 ', # need spaces 
    'url_hash': None,
    'url_stats_is_private': 0,
    'permasession': '1555801674|ole2ky65f9', # need it
}

r = requests.post('http://bit\.do/mod_perl/url-shortener.pl', headers=headers, data=data)

print(r.status_code)
print(r.json())
```

It didn't need `requests.Session()` nor `User-Agent` nor `GET` request at start.

---

**EDIT:** value `1555801674` in `'permasession': '1555801674|ole2ky65f9'` is timestamp with current date and time.

```
import datetime

datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1555801674)

datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 21, 1, 7, 54)
```

Maybe `ole2ky65f9` is also timestampe but as shortened value.

Comment: Thank you! Whitespaces helped. Also, request works without headers at all.